# Any technical case study or Q&A on StackOverflow.com?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

StackExchange sites are the best utilization of ASP.NET. Even the Microsoft's website lag way behind in user experience. It's smooth as a pie. The speed, performance, load-balancing, traffic management, client-scripting and everything else just seem perfect blend for a great Web Application.

Needless to say, it makes you bit excited to learn, as to what's going on those servers hosting them. Is there any technical case study or somewhat for this website which explains what resources, design pattern or technologies they have used. Code is not the priority but the things code uses to implement the site, like what frameworks are being used, what membership system is supported and other such tiny details would do wonders for C#.NET developers.

I tried searching(followed to this [LINK](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/07/code-its-trivial.html) too) but found nothing interesting. In fact getting the details for facebook was much easier and detailed.

Comment: Read the [blog](http://blog.stackexchange.com/). Start at the beginning. HighScalability also have a [good article](http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/3/3/stack-overflow-architecture-update-now-at-95-million-page-vi.html).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network

Comment: @AnnaLear thanks, I didn't find that earlier. Here at Meta for the first time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure this counts as a case study, but High Scalability blog had a [post](http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/3/3/stack-overflow-architecture-update-now-at-95-million-page-vi.html) a while back about SO. Lots of details.

And the [blog](http://blog.stackexchange.com/) has had updates coming in every now and then. The `server` tag is mostly about the hardware, the `design` tag is about the site features.

Comment: Awesome links man. Will get a thorough read and contact you for inside details ;-) ... Thanks

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay - I have no inside info.

Comment: Never Mind, I guess these might be enough or i will ask in the comments section of the blog if required